# Django Get All Users

Tags: python, django

I am just starting out with Django and I am messing around just trying to pull a full list of users from postgres.

I used the following code:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name="Admins")
usersList = group.user_set.all()
```

How could you pull all users?  I don't want to have to pick or assign a group.

```
group = Group.objects.get() #Doesn't Work.
usersList = group.user_set.all()
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
users = User.objects.all()
```

Comment: @Adam this is well documented, very strange you couldn't find it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all

Comment: @brandon You know I read that, and didn't realize you could do that on essentially any object.

Comment: No worries. It's just a standard Django ORM call, which exists on the model manager that exists on every model, unless overidden.

Comment: Use django.contrib.auth.get_user_model() instead of User!!! Maybe you will using a custom user model one day and use User directly will make a coding hell.

Comment: Like Zz Tux, had to downvote for not using get_user_model()

Comment: @thclark That's fine. If memory serves, the get_user_model() method wasn't even around in 2014 when I answered this question

Comment: `u = User.objects.filter(username=username)
print(u[0].is_authenticated)`

Why does `u[0].is_authenticated` always return True ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
all_users = User.objects.values()
print(all_users)
print(all_users[0]['username'])
```

`all_users` will contain all the attributes of the user. Based upon your requirement you can filter out the records.

Answer (score 6):

## Django get user it's also simple method to get all user ,create user ,change password ,etc

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
user = get_user_model()
user.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
userList =User.objects.values()
```

will return values of all user in list format from Django User table.
User.objects.all() will returns object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users = User.object.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using Basic Token Authorization
please use this but it return a dictionary

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users = User.objects.values()
```