# How to return all users in Django

Tags: python, django

I don't know how to print names of all users in my system. I got code like this:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    users = User.objects.all()
    return Response(len(users))
```

This returns only number of users but I want to get their names. What should I add to return all users names??

Comment: Did you try copying your question title into google?...

Comment: Duplicate of [Django get all users](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23139657/1324033)

Comment: This is a duplication question.

Comment: why is this closed?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is doing the following:

```
# 1. Imporing the User model from contrib package of Django
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# 2. Retrieve from the database the full list of users
users = User.objects.all()
# 3. Returns the length of the list, equiv. to the number of users so
return Response(len(users))
```

What you want to do is to return the list of names of the users. It can be done easily either by using [`.values()`/`.values_list()` on your queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) or by returning the attribute `.username` of each user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users = User.objects.all()

return Response(
    users.values_list('username', flat=True)
)
# OR
return Response(
    '\n'.join([user.username for user in users])
)
```

If by names you mean the concatenation of first name/last name, you can replace `.username` by `.get_full_name()` in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

To get their display names which is what `str(user)` returns:

```
users = [str(user) for user in User.objects.all()]
```

To get the `username` attribute values:

```
usernames = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
```