# Why is user query triggering TypeError?

Tags: django, python-3.x, typeerror

I have a CustomUser model in a Django app that I'm trying to query, but the query raises TypeError: all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Here's my user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, default= 
     'newUser', verbose_name="User Group")
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager

    # add additional fields in here
    display_name = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, help_text="XXX-XXX-XXXX")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is addressed in several posts here, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139657/django-get-all-users). So, I try this:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> User = get_user_model()
>>> userList = User.objects.all()
```

Instead of the expected queryset I get the error referencing the missing 'self' argument. The solutions I've found here for that error don't seem to work; clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: You did not create your `CustomUserManager`: `objects = CustomUserManager()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to *create* your `CustomUserManager` by *calling* the constructor (with brackets `()`):

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    # ...

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    #    call the constructor  ^^
```

By not doing so, `objects` is just a reference to the `CustomUserManager` class. If you then call `.all()`, you call the class method, and that method is indeed missing the implicit `self` parameter.